# Create child object in view as extra action

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following drf view:

```py
class HouseFullInfoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):   
    queryset = House.objects.all() 
    serializer_class = HouseSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    http_method_names = ['get', 'delete', 'post']

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        house = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(house)
        return Response(serializer.data, HTTP_200_OK)
    
    @action(methods=['delete'], detail=True, url_name='remove_habitant')
    def remove_habitant(self, request,pk=None):
        house = self.get_object()
        habitant = CustomUser.objects.get(id = request.data['id'])
        house.habitants.remove(habitant)
        return Response({'msg':'Deletion success'}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
    
    @action(methods=['delete'], detail=True, url_name='remove_vehicle')
    def remove_vehicle(self, request,pk=None):
        house = self.get_object()
        vehicle = Vehicle.objects.get(id = request.data['id'])
        house.vehicles.remove(vehicle)
        return Response({'msg':'Deletion success'}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

I am trying to make `create_habitant` and `create_vehicle` extra actions within this view, but I dont know how to do that exactly.

For `Vehicle` this would be the model:

```py
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    license_plate = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.license_plate
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I can create it using `.create()` and afterwards adding it to the house object with `vehicles.add()`

Extra steps are required due to brand being a model itself in my case.

Solution

```py
@action(methods=['post'], detail=True, url_name='create_vehicle')
    def create_vehicle(self, request,pk=None):
        house = self.get_object()
        brand = Brand.objects.get(id = request.data['brand'])
        vehicle = Vehicle.objects.create(license_plate=request.data['license_plate'], brand=brand)
        house.vehicles.add(vehicle)
        return Response({'msg':'Creation success'}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```